# NSTimer does not want to fire after fireDate is Passed

Tags: ios, ios4, nstimer, ios5

I have an `NSTimer` which fires on the current date at a specific time set by the user. For example 12:00 PM at 2012-06-22. When the user clicks a button it triggers the timer if the hour is equal to 12:00 PM. It is ok, but after this time passed the `NSTimer` triggers again when the user click the button. I do not want such behavior, so how can I do so the timer does not fire when the fire date has passed?

```
NSTimer *t = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:fireDate                                          
              interval:0.0     
              target:self
              selector:@selector(doTimerAction:)
              userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[runner addTimer:t forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[t release];
```

Comment: Are you creating the timer instance every time user clicks the button? I am not sure I understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need NSTimer for this, providing I've understood you couldn't you just do

```
-(IBAction)btnPush:(id)sender{

if (hourInput == currentHour){
[self performSelector:@selector(doAction)];
}
```

Hope this helps if no leave me a comment and ill try to help more.

Comment: geminiCoder . Actually I need timer because I want in the future to automate the fire event to happen automatically on the specified date.